# Does knowledge of the self or spiritual knowledge move from life to life?

Tags: moksha, rebirth, reference-request

I remember hearing one claim that if you don't get Moksha in this life whatever merits (spiritual actions or where you were in the spiritual rank) moves from one body to another or in other words you don't lose all your progress in your spiritual journey even from life to life, so where is the source of this claim? I suspect it might be found in the Bhagavad Gita but I am not sure what verse or chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the path of Yoga no effort is lost due to death.

> In this path of Yoga - the path of selfless action combined with
> devotion - **no effort is lost due to incompleteness and no contrary
> effect of an adverse nature is produced due to failures.** Even a little
> observance of this discipline saves one from great fear.

**Gita 2.40**

> "Yayati answered, 'The wise, with the help of the Vedas and of
> Knowledge, having ascertained the visible universe to be illusory,
> instantly realises the Supreme Spirit as the sole existent independent
> essence. While they that devote themselves to Yoga meditation take
> time to acquire the same knowledge, for it is by practice alone that
> these latter divest themselves of the consciousness of quality. Hence
> the wise attain to salvation first. **Then again if the person devoted
> to Yoga find not sufficient time in one life to attain success, being
> led astray by the attractions of the world, in his next life he is
> benefited by the progress already achieved, for he devoteth himself
> regretfully to the pursuit of success.** But the man of knowledge ever
> beholdeth the indestructible unity, and, is, therefore, though steeped
> in worldly enjoyments, never affected by them at heart. Therefore,
> there is nothing to impede his salvation. He, however, who faileth to
> attain to knowledge, should yet devote himself to piety as dependent
> on action (sacrifices &c.). But he that devoteth himself to such
> piety, moved thereto by desire of salvation, can never achieve
> success. His sacrifices bear no fruit and partake of the nature of
> cruelty. Piety which is dependent on action that proceedeth not from
> the desire of fruit, is, in case of such men Yoga itself.'

**Mahabharata Adi Parva Section XCII**